# How to add a number to a DynamoDB number set using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm just trying to add a number to a number set in DynamoDB. This expression was working with an untyped list. But to save space since it will just be storing numbers I moved everything to plain number sets. Now no matter how much I tinker with it I can't get it to go through.

```
var phoneID = req.body.PhoneID;
var category = req.body.ratingCategory;
var ratingToAdd = [Number(req.body.rating)]

var dbparams = {
"TableName": "Venue_Ratings",
Key: {
   "PhoneID" : phoneID
},
"UpdateExpression": "SET #categoryName =  list_append(#categoryName, :rating)",
"ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
    "#categoryName" : category
},
"ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":rating": ratingToAdd
},
"ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
};
```

This error is being thrown `An operand in the update expression has an incorrect data type`

I have also tried changing the update expression to an `ADD` expression instead like so `ADD #categoryName :rating`.

I've tried changing `ratingToAdd` to a plain number not in an array, a string in an array, and a plain string not in an array.

I'm calling the db using the `docClient.update` method.

I have verified that the sets in the db are in fact number sets and that they exist.

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The below code should add the number to the **Number Set (i.e. DynamoDB data type 'NS').**

**Use this function with ADD in UpdateExpression:-**

```
docClient.createSet([Number(5)])
```

**Code:-**

```
var params = {
        TableName : "Movies",
        Key : {
            "yearkey" : 2016,
            "title" : "The Big New Movie 1"
        },
        UpdateExpression : "ADD #category :categorySet",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#category' : 'category'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {':categorySet' : docClient.createSet( [Number(5)])},
        ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
    };
```